# OData GetById is not working on Asp.net Core 2.2

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, .net-core, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to get a single item from my list of elements and it is not working. I am using FromODataUri correctly, I am not seeing what is wrong.
I am able to hit this resource:
https://localhost:44314/odata/Inventories
but I can't  get a single item: https://localhost:44314/odata/Inventories(1)

This is how my Startup.cs looks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Extensions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.OData.Edm;
using OdataTest.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;

namespace OdataTest
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddOData();
            services.AddODataQueryFilter();

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "Inventory Api", Version = "v1" });
            });

            services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseSwagger();

            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                // force to add another /swagger to fix issue
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Physical Inventory API");
            });

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc(b =>
                   b.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel(app.ApplicationServices))
                );
        }

        private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(serviceProvider);
            builder.Namespace = "PartsInventory";
            builder.ContainerName = "PartsInventoryContainer";

            builder.EntitySet<InventoryOutputDto>("Inventories").EntityType
                .Filter()
                .Count()
                .Expand()
                .OrderBy()
                .Page()
                .Select();

            return builder.GetEdmModel();
        }
    }
}
```

And my Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using OdataTest.Models;

namespace OdataTest.Controllers
{
    public class PartsInventoryController : ODataController
    {
        List<InventoryOutputDto> list = new List<InventoryOutputDto>() {
                new InventoryOutputDto {
                    Description = "Description1",
                    UserName = "user1",
                    EndDate = DateTime.Now,
                    ErrorId = "Error",
                    InventoryId = 1,
                    LocationCode = 1,
                    StartDate = DateTime.Now,
                    StatusCode = 1
                },
                new InventoryOutputDto {
                    Description = "Description1",
                    UserName = "user1",
                    EndDate = DateTime.Now,
                    ErrorId = "Error2",
                    InventoryId = 2,
                    LocationCode = 2,
                    StartDate = DateTime.Now,
                    StatusCode = 2
                } };

        [HttpGet]
        [ODataRoute("Inventories")]
        ///  public IActionResult Inventory(InventoryInputDto inputDto)
        public IActionResult GetInventories(InventoryInputDto inputDto)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, list);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [ODataRoute("Inventories({key})")]
        public IActionResult GetInventoryById([FromODataUri] int key)
        {
            var invRecord = list.FirstOrDefault(i => i.InventoryId == key);

            if(invRecord == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(invRecord);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "OData GetById is not working": Could you please show us what error did you get?  I copy & paste your code, but it works fine for me.

Comment: Is not reaching the controller. On the output I am not getting any error

Comment: I test it with `ASP.NET Core v2.2.402` + `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData v7.2.1`) again. But it works fine for me. Is there a demo that reproduces?